# get-wmiobject parallel processing to find device on all domain computers

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a domain where there are M2 SATA drives installed in some of the laptops. We would like to locate and remove the M2s. I have a script that will take a list of IP addresses in a *.csv using `get-content` and output a computer name with the drive we are looking for.

```
function FindM2 {
process {
$dd = gwmi win32_diskdrive -comp $_ | Where-Object {$_.model -eq 'SC2 M2 SSD'} -    ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$cs = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$obj = new-object psobject
$obj | add-member noteproperty CompName $cs.name
$obj | add-member noteproperty SSD $dd.model
write-output $obj
}}
```

This works, but takes forever when it has to wait for a timeout on a non-responsive host. I was thinking it may be beneficial to run many background processes in parallel, but I don't know how to do this. Any thoughts for speeding this up when scanning over 1000 addresses?

If I could figure how to do this as a foreach loop I would try that. Maybe something more like:

```
$cn = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=MyDomain,DC=local" | Select Name
foreach ($name in $cn){
process {
$dd = gwmi win32_diskdrive -comp $_ | Where-Object {$_.model -eq 'SC2 M2 SSD'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$cs = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$obj = new-object psobject
$obj | add-member noteproperty CompName $cs.name
$obj | add-member noteproperty SSD $dd.model
write-output $obj
}}
```

Thank you to those out there who might assist me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could run them as jobs, and then toss in a Do/While loop after that to get the jobs that are done (say, every half minute) so long as there are jobs left. Something like:

```
$cn = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=MyDomain,DC=local" | Select Name
foreach ($name in $cn){
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $dd = gwmi win32_diskdrive -comp $Name.name | Where-Object {$_.model -eq 'SC2 M2 SSD'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $cs = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $Name.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $obj = new-object psobject
    $obj | add-member noteproperty CompName $cs.name
    $obj | add-member noteproperty SSD $dd.model
    $obj
}
$Results = @()
Do{$Results += Get-Job -State Completed; $results | FT -Auto; start-sleep 30}while(Get-Job)
```

Comment: Thanks MadTechnician. Running jobs looks awesome and I appreciate the advice. How could we have the completed jobs append their name and model output to a single variable? Then every 30 seconds (where you have the job state) it could be interesting to display the table, it would be like it was refreshing. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer. Added an empty array `$Results` and then added each job's response to that array, and displayed it as a table.

Comment: For testing purposes I used a .csv with a few known present names with the script you posted. Whether used with get-adcomputer or import-csv each job always returns that the computername argument is null or empty 
    Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException

Comment: You probably need to reference the property that represents the actual name within the object. So for the Get-ADComputer you would do `$Name.name` on the $dd= and $cs= lines.